# Python too short if condition

Tags: python, if-statement

I want this condition to be short if it's possible, I don't want every time `or`

```
if not wall.twitter_access_token or not wall.twitter_access_token_secret or not wall.auth_user:
    raise Exception("Cannot open without verify with twitter account")
```

Comment: `not a or not b` is equivalent to `not (a and b) `

Comment: The right thing to do is refactor (extract) it to a function and call it: `if verify_twitter_account():...`

Answer (score 4):

```
if not wall.twitter_access_token or not wall.twitter_access_token_secret or not wall.auth_user:
```

can be equivalently written as employing [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
if not(wall.twitter_access_token and wall.twitter_access_token_secret and wall.auth_user)
```

or even better using the built-in [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

```
if not all([wall.twitter_access_token, 
            wall.twitter_access_token_secret, 
            wall.auth_user]):
```

moreover, the last expression is more readable considering the fact it is `when not all are true`.

nevertheless, if you would repeat the expression multiple times, employ DRY principle and refactor it to a function.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is by using [.all()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function. Your code will be like:

```
if not all([
    wall.twitter_access_token, 
    wall.twitter_access_token_secret, 
    wall.auth_user,
    ]):
```

**Note:** It is a good practice to place each of your list elements into a new line. It is more readable, and you may just comment the line to skip one condition (useful while debugging).